# Converting select inside case statement

Tags: sql, presto

I have a select query that contains case statement which in-turn has select query inside it.

SQL:

```
with emp_data as(
    select id, *
    from table_a
),
final_data as(
    select *,
        case when a.id in (select id from emp_data) then 1 else 0 end as valid_id
    from emp_data a
    left join corp_data b on a.id = b.id
)
```

Could you tell me how effectively I can have the select statement inside CASE statement to be not part of the case statement? If I understand the working on SQL engine, this select inside CASE would run for each run which may not be optimal for large data set. Please advise.

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Tagging multiple conflicting technologies makes your question unclear and thus *harder* to answer. It is also unlikely to get your question "more views" and likely to have the opposite effect, where only users who know *all* the RDBMS you have (mis)tagged will entertain the question; that is often a very small portion of the user base. Tag spam is far more likely to result in your question receiving downvotes and/or being closed as unclear. Please [edit] your question to retag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: Trust the optimizer. Or check the execution plan.

Comment: BTW, that's a `case` _expression_.

Comment: Thank you ! Is there a way to take the case statement out and have it as a left join? Presto doesn't seem to accept a select within a select

Comment: _" If I understand the working on SQL engine, this select inside CASE would run for each run which may not be optimal for large data set."_ - not necessarily - use [`explain`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/explain.html) to check if your assertion is true. Also potentially SQL engine can use hash search with hash being build one time so the cost can be lowered.

Comment: Also I would argue that `select id, * from` is pointless, t least in the provided query.

Comment: Also isn't `case when a.id in (select id from emp_data) then 1 else 0 ` always 1 cause `a` is `emp_data` itself? Please add relevant [mre] cause current one does not make much sense.